# Setting the applicationId in gradle for a combined product flavor

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-productflavors

I have an app with two `productFlavors`:

```
flavorDimensions "type", "country"

productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "type"
    }
    premium {
        dimension "type"
    }
    us {
        dimension "country"
    }
    de {
        dimension "country"
    }
}
```

This leads to four `buildVariants` (ignoring build types).

Now my challenge is to set different `applicationId`s for these four variants but I cannot figure out how to do this.
The only way I found to actually change the `applicationId` is inside the `productFlavors` definition like so:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "some.application.id"
        dimension "type"
    }
```

but the problem is, that the `flavor` is actually `freeDe` for instance and I would like to set the `applicationId` for that combined one.

I tried:

```
productFlavors {
    freeDe {
        applicationId "some.random.id"
    }
```

and

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        de {
            applicationId "some.random.id"
        }
    }
```

and a bunch of other combinations but none of them seem to work.

Important: I cannont use pre/suffix for that as the application ids are totally different from each other :(

Help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor
    switch (variant.flavorName) {
        case "freeUs":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.application.id.freeUs")
            break
        case "freeDe":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.application.id.freeDe")
            break

    }
}
```

Comment: no, I don't need to set a suffix I need to change the whole applicationId based on a predefined pattern that has no relation to the existing applicationId.

Comment: that seems to work, but I cannot confirm 100% yet as now I run into a new issue where resources can't be found for the selected buildVariant. :(